# Share folders on Exchange 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, imap, exchange-2010

Is there a possibility to share folders (mainly inbox folder) according to an ACL on Exchange, using IMAP structure or native Exchange sharing?

For example, I have a team with A, B, C and D. We want each people of the team to see the inbox folders of the others.

So, we want to create a team mailbox and add shared inbox of members of the team into it.

Is there a way to do that under Exchange, without making heavy things like forwarding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only share Tasks, Calendar, Contacts or Journal folders. The only way to share Mail folders is to share the entire mailbox.